# bootstrap: create of carousel of texts only

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a carousel of text only.

I copied the original example from http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel, removed the images and look at some other examples.

```
<div id="carousel-example-captions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>First slide label</h3>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Second slide label</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Third slide label</h3>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-captions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-captions" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yamikep/esy38/15/

However, the indicators are not well aligned now. What makes that happen?

Is there a simple way to have a carousel of text with bootstrap?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The .carousel-indicator class has absolute positioning.  The bottom property is set in media queries.  You can override this in your css by adding the following:

```
.carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Do you know whether there is a way to handle content of different length? For example, the 3rd slide is longer in this example http://jsfiddle.net/yamikep/esy38/66/ and it makes the size of the container change from one slide to another. Would be great if the size of the bigger one can be set and the texts are aligned in the middle but I'm not sure whether that is possible.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to handle this.  Getting the text vertically centered while sliding (versus sliding into place and then centering) likely requires a little javascript magic.  If you post another question, I'll be happy to post a couple of options and maybe someone else will even have a better solution. (It just not easily answered in a comment).